# Can Google Cloud Dataflow be run without an external IP address in Go?

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#python) it's possible to run Dataflow without using public IP. But it only have information for Java and Python. I'm not able to find a way to do it in Go :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
`IpConfiguration:         "WORKER_IP_PRIVATE"`

Like this for context:

```
    response := dataflowService.Projects.Locations.Templates.Create(PROJECT_ID, location, &dataflow.CreateJobFromTemplateRequest{
    Environment: &dataflow.RuntimeEnvironment{
        AdditionalExperiments:   []string{},
        AdditionalUserLabels:    map[string]string{},
        BypassTempDirValidation: false,
        EnableStreamingEngine:   false,
        IpConfiguration:         "WORKER_IP_PRIVATE",
        KmsKeyName:              "",
        MachineType:             "",
        MaxWorkers:              0,
        Network:                 "",
        NumWorkers:              0,
        ServiceAccountEmail:     "",
        Subnetwork:              "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/" + HOST_PROJECT_ID + "/regions/europe-north1/subnetworks/" + SUBNETWORK + "",
        TempLocation:            "",
        WorkerRegion:            "",
        WorkerZone:              "",
        Zone:                    "",
        ForceSendFields:         []string{},
        NullFields:              []string{},
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Go is not yet officially supported on Dataflow (hence the lack of documentation), but the [same flags](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.32.0/sdks/go/pkg/beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow.go#L61) exist in the Go SDK and should work exactly the same way.